# Perplexing "Invalid Constructor Name" in Dart

Tags: dart

This is pretty much my first bit of dart and I've got totally stuck. Android Studio is underlining the constructor with "Invalid Constructor Name". The form follows the examples, so I'm scratching my head here.

```
class AvailableWord{

  String word;
  String nativeWord;
  String audioFilename;
  String nativeAudioFilename;

  AvailableWord(this.word,
      this.nativeWord,
      this.audioFilename,
      this.nativeAudioFilename);

}
```

Any clue?

Comment: If I paste the code into dartpad.dartlang.org, I get no warning or error. Are you sure Android Studio is recognizing the code as Dart?

Comment: The editor tab has the flutter icon. It does seem bizarre. Looking forward to finding out what the cause is. https://imgur.com/a/4U0RKFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post this. The editor needed some kind of refresh. Closing and re-opening Android Studio fixed it. Weirdly I've not had this problem since.